# Mysql query optimisation to transform subquery in join without DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I have tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bk_cart_rule` (
  `id_cart_rule` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cart_rule_restriction` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `id_cart_rule` (`id_cart_rule`),
  KEY `cart_rule_restriction` (`cart_rule_restriction`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bk_cart_rule_combination` (
  `id_cart_rule_1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_cart_rule_2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `id_cart_rule_1` (`id_cart_rule_1`),
  KEY `id_cart_rule_2` (`id_cart_rule_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bk_cart_rule_lang` (
  `id_cart_rule` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_lang` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `id_cart_rule` (`id_cart_rule`),
  KEY `id_lang` (`id_lang`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And a query :

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE cr.*, crl.*, 1 as selected FROM bk_cart_rule cr 
LEFT JOIN bk_cart_rule_lang crl ON (cr.id_cart_rule = crl.id_cart_rule AND crl.id_lang = 2)

 WHERE cr.id_cart_rule != 375 AND
             (   cr.cart_rule_restriction = 0 OR 
                 cr.id_cart_rule IN ( 
                    SELECT IF(id_cart_rule_1 = 375, id_cart_rule_2, id_cart_rule_1) FROM bk_cart_rule_combination WHERE 375 = id_cart_rule_1 OR 375 = id_cart_rule_2 ) )
```

Obvious optimization is:

```
    SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT cr.*, crl.* 1 as selected FROM bk_cart_rule cr 
LEFT JOIN bk_cart_rule_lang crl ON (cr.id_cart_rule = crl.id_cart_rule AND crl.id_lang = 2) 
LEFT JOIN bk_cart_rule_combination crc ON (375 = crc.id_cart_rule_1 AND  cr.id_cart_rule = crc.id_cart_rule_2) OR (375 = crc.id_cart_rule_2  AND cr.id_cart_rule = crc.id_cart_rule_1)
WHERE  cr.id_cart_rule != 375 AND (cr.cart_rule_restriction = 0 OR NOT ISNULL(crc.id_cart_rule_1))
```

But how can i get rid off DISTINCT (in bk_cart_rule_combination I've two-way combinations : )

```
id_cart_rule_1 id_cart_rule_2
 375  776
 776  375
```

Or maybe there is a better optimization possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the ordering of the cart rules is not important, then add the constraint that the id for the first one is less than the id of the second one.  That is, put them in the table in order.

Sadly, MySQL doesn't allow simple `check` constraints.  Instead, you have to implement it in some other way.  Here are three:

- Implement an insert/update trigger to maintain the ordering (and prevent duplicates).
- Implement the logic on the application side.
- Wrap all data modifications in stored procedures and implement the logic in the stored procedure.

If you don't want to go through all that trouble (which would probably help with other issues), you can replace the `select distinct` with:

```
group by least(id_cart_rule_1,  id_cart_rule_2), greatest(id_cart_rule_1,  id_cart_rule_2)
```